# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data While Adding Second Parameter To Fetch Function

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch-api

I have a fetch function, but when I'm adding second parameter, it's will thrown an error, but if I removed it, the code will run, so, what I don't understand is why it's thrown an error? I'm still want second parameter for another purposes.

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

My code

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/PWA-order/menu", {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseData => console.log(responseData));
```

It will returning an error.

But if the code is:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/PWA-order/menu")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseData => console.log(responseData));
```

The response is success.

> Update

If the second parameter is "header" it will work, but if the second parameter is "headers" it will thrown an error"

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/PWA-order/menu", {
  header: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseData => console.log(responseData));

fetch("http://localhost:5000/PWA-order/menu", {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => console.log(responseData));
```

The full function is:

```
const fetchAPI = async (url, bodyValue, method, jwt) => {
    try {
        const headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': jwt != null ? `Bearer ${jwt}` : null
        }
        const body = bodyValue ?? null;
        const paramater = {
            headers: headers,
            method: method,
            body
        }
        const response = await fetch(url, paramater);
        const result = await response.json();
        if(result){
            return Promise.resolve(result);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Error', response.status);
            return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
        }
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: And the _"second"_ parameter is what? `bodyValue` or `parameter`? And what is the content of the "second parameter"?

Comment: From the full fetch function, the second paramater is a variable named parameter which an object returning headers object, method object which takes from parameter, and body object. Forget it. 

What i confuse is when i adding the second paramater from the fetch() function it will thrown an error. Example if the function is only
fetch("http://localhost:5000/PWA-order/menu")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseData => console.log(responseData));

The response is succes without an error, but when i adding second parameter (fetch(url, {header{})). It will thrown an error

Comment: The question is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the response is not in JSON format. Try it:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/PWA-order/menu", {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  },
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(responseData => console.log(responseData));
```

Comment: Question updated, the correct name for second parameter is header or headers ? it succes if i use "header" rather than "headers"

Comment: correct is "headers"

Comment: @MuhammadSyabaniFalif [it's header*s*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). The reason it "succeeds" when you use header without the 's' is that the fetch completely ignores the misspelt one and defaults to text instead of application/json. This answer is likely correct your response isn't valid JSON.

Comment: So the error is from the api itself ? not from my function ?

Comment: Most likely yes.